Function calls to unmapped memory
I'm examining an iOS framework (extracted from a dyld shared cache) and there are a lot of branch-link instructions to functions which don't exist.  For example,
bl #-0x50e7e04

Performing the arithmetic based on the next function address, that's a call to 0x194151e140.  However, running
otool -l <framework> | grep addr | awk '{print $NF}' | sort

reveals the lowest memory address corresponding to a mapped file is 0x1990da000.
Is this some RE countermeasure?  What's going on here?
For context, this is from the private framework CMCapture from iOS 14.5.  The machine code is
7f 60 bc 96

at address 0x199245f44.

I'm not familiar with this environment, but could you share the address of this instruction and the byte code (just 4 bytes). At first it seems you're not disassembling a valid instruction: it could be data or being encrypted.

The instruction seems correctly encoded, and I can't personally obtain this file. Can you try to disassemble it with Ghidra or equivalent? Can you tell if the instructions around this bl look corrects?

In iOS, the system frameworks are loaded together and often reference each other directly.
If you're using Ghidra, you can get it to resolve these references by importing the shared cache as a file system and then importing the frameworks from that file system.  You can then right-click on the reference (which will be highlighted in red), and click "References -> Add to Program".  It is important to note that the "Add to program" option will only appear if you imported in the manner described.
